# Time difference calculation when values accepted in 24 hour format

Tags: c#

In C#, I am accepting 2 time values in textboxes and want to calculate the time between these 2 times. The times are accepted in 24 hour format as hhmm. There is no any semicolon or . is used in between hrs and mins.

I have tried following code :

```
DateTime ts1 = DateTime.Parse(TextBox3.Text);
DateTime ts2 = DateTime.Parse(TextBox4.Text);
TimeSpan ts = ts2-ts1;
TextBox12.Text = Convert.ToString(ts);
```

Getting the error as

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Suppose `TextBox3.Text = 0800` and `TextBox4.Text = 2000` then `TextBox12.Text = 12`

Please help.

Comment: `TimeSpan.Parse` not `DateTime.parse` should work better, parsing times as dates makes no sense. And the values entered will need to conform to the specification here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx . Also I'm not sure if a simple numerical subtraction will serve to actually subtract one timespan from another. You might need to use one of the manipulation methods on the TimeSpan object to get an accurate result.

Comment: If the textboxes contain only time, why are you trying to parse dates? Try [TimeSpan.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have tried the TimeSpan.Parse but its not showing the correct result.

Comment: Like I said, the values entered will need to conform to the specification here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx . Currently I don't believe that they do as per your example data. Also please use  TimeSpan.Subtract thttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.subtract(v=vs.110).aspx to perform your subtract operation, then you get back a new TimeSpan and can output from it in the format you desire (currently, it won't know whether to output hours or minutes or seconds or whatever)

Comment: Use datetimepicker instead of textbox.

Comment: @KemalGüler how will this help, exactly? The issue is how the data is being parsed on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three problems:

1) Trying to parse times as dates. Using `DateTime.Parse` is inappropriate here.

2) Even if you use `TimeSpan.Parse`, your example data does not conform to the required format for the parse method to recognise it. The accepted formats are shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx For the time part, you would need at least to include a colon (`:`) between the hours and minutes in your input, e.g. `08:00`.

So you can either do that, or use `TimeSpan ts1 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(TextBox3.Text, "hhmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` in order to give it a custom format to recognise.

3) You should use the `TimeSpan.Subtract` method to accurately deduct one time period from the other. Currently just using `-` is unlikely to work, and the system will not know whether you want the output in hours, minutes, seconds or anything else.

```
TextBox12.Text = ts2.Subtract(ts1).Hours
```

Should give you what you want.

You probably ought to consider some other prior validation as well - checking that ts2 is actually greater than ts1 before allowing the input, and maybe using `TryParseExact` to attempt to parse the input and return true/false, in case the user has input the value incorrectly (you will get a `FormatException` from the `Parse` or `ParseExact` method if there's an incorrect input).

Answer (score 1):

Since the format of the text in your text boxes is not the "default" date / time format the call to `TimeSpan.Parse()` fails / returns wrong results. (You are using a format without a colon `:` character for separating the hours and minutes).

In this case you'll need to specify the format explicitly, for example using the [`TimeSpan.ParseExact()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992370(v=vs.110).aspx).

The following example parses the text `"0854"` into a `TimeSpan` value, representing the time `08:54`

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact("0854", "hhmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Thanks Bassfader, it is working but not showing the desired result. Suppose that Departure time is 2000 and arrival time is 0900 then the result must be 13:00:00 but it is showing -11:00:00

Comment: @AtulPatil 20-9 = 11. Where do you get 13 from?

Comment: @ADyson 20 means 8PM and 9 means 9 AM. So on the first day, it will be having 24-20 = 4 hours and next day's 9 hours. So 4+9= 13 hours.

Comment: @bassfader thanks for the answer, its working but i could not figure out the conversion of datatypes here. I am sorry but I am new to all this. Using timespan for the first time. After your suggestions I did the changes as follows :

Comment: `int temp = 0;
                TimeSpan ts1 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(TextBox3.Text, "hhmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                TimeSpan ts2 = TimeSpan.ParseExact(TextBox4.Text, "hhmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                if (ts1 < ts2)
                {
                    temp = Convert.ToInt32(ts2) - Convert.ToInt32(ts1);
                }
                if (ts1 > ts2)
                {
                    temp = (24 - Convert.ToInt32(ts1))+ Convert.ToInt32(ts2);
             }
TextBox12.Text = Convert.ToString(temp);`